# Android GridView spacing and center issue

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/homeGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="200dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

1. I have four icons in my grid view, but the spacing between them is
   too much. I want to reduce it.
2. Also i want to make the GridView center to the device, but it always
   stays at top.

Answer (score 6):

You should use dimension to overcome this issue.
Just define dimension for each density screen.

- **values-ldpi**
- **values-mdpi**
- **values-hdpi**
- **values-xhdpi**
- **values-large**

values-ldpi/dimesion.xml

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="grid_vertical_space">15dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-mdpi/dimesion.xml

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="grid_vertical_space">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-hdpi/dimesion.xml

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="grid_vertical_space">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Like wise..

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/homeGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="200dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vertical_space" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, the horizontal space is still the same shown in the image and the entire grid is not coming down...

Answer (score 0):

If your layout is composed only of 4 icons, why don't you use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) with 2 [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)? I think you can achieve what you want more easily, because:

1. you can define the spacing between items;
2. also you can center your table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570372/making-the-gridview-center-in-android can you help me out in this thread... i have almost done but yet not able to do it... i don't want to use TableLayout and TableRow.

Comment: @theJava done, but if you have an answer for this thread, publish it ;) .