# Making the gridView center in Android

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/homeGridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="160dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="none"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have been breaking my head on how to make the gridView center horizonal and vertical. I have also attached my screen-shot for the same.
Below is my image code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried ->  android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: yes i tried @Santhosh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816004/center-elements-in-gridview

Comment: it is completely fine...if it still not works try removing this from your code `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: or you can make your parent layout to linear layout if you wish

Comment: if you hardcode the layout_width of gridview to twice that of each gridview Item(column) instead of wrap_content it will display at the center. But, i don't think if you like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you don't want to use TableLayout ([as you says in your precedent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567153/android-gridview-spacing-and-center-issue/15570343?noredirect=1#comment22070028_15570343)), dealing with GridView is pretty complicated (i've lost a lot of times on this).
The only idea i have his to force your GridView to have an exact width, that is the sum of your 2 views: 160dip * 2.

```
    android:layout_width="320dip"
```

Feel free to add 10dip or more for padding.

**N.B.:** i'm not sure if this is the best way and if this is proper for every device. Try it and let me know ;) .

Comment: Quick question: my image size is 150dp, should the column width be also 150dp or more

Comment: @theJava You can leave this size, but try it and see if it is more beautiful and what's changing on your layout.

Comment: In Galaxy tab, there is no spacing between the icons, but in nexus there is a horizontal space coming in....

Comment: @theJava sincerely i don't know why: does they are both with JB?

Comment: @JaAd, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use these 2 tags inside ur gridview see if it works

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Can u just remove gravity tags and centerInParent tag both in Gridview and relativelayout and only use these 2 in gridview and see...

Comment: I tried the above too, it does not make any change... http://pastie.org/private/zfinfrxvxmwirw0yvr5qg