# how Center elements in GridView?

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter

I have an requirement of :
[image]

I have a layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/category_bg">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerlinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/category_header"

            >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logosmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A Cafe With Arabian Food"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="11pt"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logosmall"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choosetxtview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose a Category"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11pt"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--  <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/textlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerlinearlayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >


    </LinearLayout> -->

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_above="@+id/footerlinearlayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerlinearlayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">

        <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="120dip"

                android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:verticalSpacing="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerlinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/category_footer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            >

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/backbtn_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/backbtn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/homebtn_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backbtn_iv"
                android:background="@drawable/homebtn"/>


        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/helpbtn_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/helpbtn"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"

                />


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_poweredby"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/powerd_by"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

response is: 
[image]

please help i have tried so many things.

Comment: are you welcome for answers with using linear layout instead grid view?

Comment: @Rajiv yadav Have you figure out the solution?

Comment: same question here, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using layout_span attribute of `TableRow`. Just add

```
android:layout_span="2"
```

in child element of `TableRow`

You can also do it programatically like this..

```
//theChild in this case is the child of TableRow
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) theChild.getLayoutParams();
params.span = 2; //amount of columns you will span
theChild.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with GridView is really an headache, and is difficult to obtain your layout if you don't want to use TableLayout and TableRow.
Your question is similar to [another question here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570372/making-the-gridview-center-in-android/15570654#15570654), where i already answered.

My idea is to "force" GridView to have an exact width, that is the sum of your columns width, for example: you can take the width of your ImageView that compose the grid and multiplicate width*columns. Then you can programmatically set total width to your GrdiView by LayoutParams.